# Photoshop layers to batch icons?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, icon, photoshop-scripting

I am trying to save out 24 rasterized layers to icon format. Is there a script to do this?

I have tried greenfish but it does not let me set a custom size 100x100

I have also tried batching as png to irfanview then using irfan view to convert png to ico but the transparency does not save out clearly.

Anyone have a workflow on how to get this working?

thanks

Comment: What version of Photoshop are you using?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if I understood what you are trying to do. How I don't have enough reputation to comment, I will write this step-by-step answer.

Have you tried using an action to do the work?

Open any image on photoshop, then create a new action. All you have to do is open the window Actions (option + F9), and click the blank paper icon to create a new Action. Name it the way you want. Then do the work, resize the image, and then stop recording.

Now go to File > Automate > Batch and select the action you created and the folder where the images are located.

If I understood you well, this should do the job.

Comment: the last part of this puzzle is ICO format. AFAIK, you need a plugin for Photoshop. For some reason the name "telegraphics" comes to mind regarding a free plugin but I have not used it.